# ERROR: attempted to read an unexpected stripe while reading columnar table daily_p2022_10_11, stripe with id=281134 is not flushed

Tags: postgresql-14, citus

I am getting this error in postgres alert log:
ERROR: attempted to read an unexpected stripe while reading columnar table daily_p2022_10_11, stripe with id=281134 is not flushed.

While trying vacuum, getting below :
ccap_proddb=> vacuum verbose daily_p2022_10_11;
ERROR:  invalid columnar chunk entry
DETAIL:  Chunk number out of range: 0

Not able to execute - Select count(*) from  daily_p2022_10_11;

We have postgres 14.2 and citus 11.0-1

Comment: What version of columnar are you using?
Could you the share steps to reproduce those errors?
More specifically,
CREATE TABLE command that you used to create the columnar table, including indexes (if any).
What columnar.chunk_group_row_limit, columnar.compression, columnar.compression_level and columnar.stripe_row_limit are set to before creating the table.
And the output of the following:
SELECT * FROM columnar.stripe where stripe_num = 281134;
SELECT * FROM columnar.options where relation = 'daily_p2022_10_11'::regclass;

Comment: We are using CITUS for columnar DB and version used is :  citus 11.0-1.

Comment: I have checked the particular stripe_id and it has only 11 records. Can you please guide as how to related storage_id in columnar.stripe with table_name i.e. regclass in columnar.options

Comment: Hey @user2873848, you're right, we should also have told you how to relate storage_id to regclass.  Here is how you can do:

storage_id = columnar.get_storage_id('daily_p2022_10_11');`

Comment: ERROR:  attempted to read an unexpected stripe while reading columnar table ccap_msc_cdr_daily_summary_p2022_12_04, stripe with id=39799 is not flushed
We have postgres 14.2 and citus-11.0-1.

please help as this error is coming multiple times and tables are becoming unreadable.